# How to set User Agent in QtWebEngine QML application

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, user-agent, qtwebengine

> NOTE: I was able to do that on QtWebKit QML using the [QtWebView extension](http://rschroll.github.io/beru/2013/08/21/qtwebview.experimental.html). Here I am interested in using **QtWebEngine**.

My simple test application

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtWebEngine 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    color: "lightgray"
    visible: true
    WebEngineView {
        id: webview
        url: "http://stackexchange.com/"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

How do I pass a different [**User Agent** string](http://useragentstring.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interested in using QtWebEngine too. And I can suggest you use QtWebEngine developers [Trello](https://trello.com/b/5G9c1rkb/qtwebengine).

As you can see in **Todo for 5.5** this is [currently under development](https://trello.com/c/zrlQmETo/145-api-to-set-the-useragent) and may be done in 5.5.

Comment: Excellent note indeed. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

// import QtWebEngine 1.4

```
WebEngineView {
    id: webview
    url: "http://stackexchange.com/"
    anchors.fill: parent
    profile:  WebEngineProfile{
        httpUserAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From Qt 5.5 onwards, you can set the [WebEngineProfile.userAgent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineprofile.html#httpUserAgent-prop) property.